# Date time parsing error from string format

Tags: android, simpledateformat, datetime-format, date-parsing

I am trying to get the date format from a string which is saved in sharedpreferences.[image: datetime parsing error]

As you can see the wrong date in the picture.current date is 19/11/2015 but after parsing it is changed to "Mon Jul 11 ..."something.please find some help for me.
Thank you.

Comment: come on man!how can you negative this question.if you think this is a silly question then answer back.(sorry guys this is not for all,this is just for the one who gave negative vote.)

Comment: Correct your format. `m` is used for *Minute in hour* whereas `M` is used as *Month in year*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dateobg returning from web service is : 11-19-2015.

You try to get the date from this string, you should in this case use the correct SimpleDateFormat.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
```

Comment: Thanks buddy.Actually i din't observe the format that i am receiving.thanks again.

Comment: but still i din't solve the issue.it is now showing as Mon Jan 19 2015

Comment: Show the response of your web service again.

Comment: yeah it worked now for me after a little change in the code.Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` for that

```
public String getDateTime(){    
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date date = new Date();
    return format.format(date)+"" ; 
}
```

Comment: The question is asking about converting string to date, isn't it?