# How get date in "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" format properly

Tags: android

```
String date = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", new java.util.Date());
```

Is some device work ok. But in other devices I get:

> 2015-12-24 HH:28:24

In devices that not work if I change (HH) - > (hh) works. But I need hour in 24 hour mode.

Comment: used `SimpleDateFormat` instead of `DateFormat`. check [This Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28559224/display-date-in-24-hour-issue)

Comment: Check my [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33799613/2553431)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use `kk` instead of `hh` for instance:

```
String date = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss", new java.util.Date());
```

Or use `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
formatter.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

Check out documentation: [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

> H  - Hour in day (0-23)
>
> k  - Hour in day (1-24)
>
> K  - Hour in am/pm (0-11)
>
> h  - Hour in am/pm (1-12)

Answer (score 1):

You can use as:

```
    Date dt = new Date();

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");



    String check = dateFormat.format(dt);


    System.out.println("DATE_TO_FROM_DATEBASE   " + 
            arrayOfStringDate[d].toString());
    System.out.println("CURRENT_DATE   " + check);
```

Hope so this may help you.